# Append style only to nodes in the graphic area of an axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, matlab2tikz

I am currently using `matlab2tikz` to export graphical data to `latex`.

Some of the plots I use contain both `pgfplots` objects such as `\addplot`  and `tikz` objects such as `\node` or `\draw` in potentially large amounts.

I would like to be able to apply a global style modification to all `\node`s of the graphical area of the `axis`, hence excluding all nodes related to legends, axis labels, ticks, ...

I tried some options but so far, I was not able to apply a style globally with the required result.

There might be an element of answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329315/pgfplotsset-append-style-is-not-appended-to-tikzpicture-axis-environment), but I failed to transpose it to this case.

Here is a MWE showing the required result and some failing solutions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Reference
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:10] {x};
\node[fill=orange,draw=black] at (axis cs: (5,5) {Hello World};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Desired result
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:10] {x};
\node[fill=orange,draw=black,inner sep=0pt] at (axis cs: (5,5) {Hello World};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Non working solution 1 : nothing seems to happen
\begin{axis}[every node/.append style={inner sep=0pt}]
\addplot[domain=0:10] {x};
\node[fill=orange,draw=black] at (axis cs: (5,5) {Hello World};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Non working solution 2 : ticks are also modified
\tikzset{every node/.append style={inner sep=0pt}}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:10] {x};
\node[fill=orange,draw=black] at (axis cs: (5,5) {Hello World};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> Reference
>   [image]
>
> Desired result
>   [image]
>
> Non working solutions
>   [image]
>   [image]

**EDIT** I ended up using @marmot 's answer adding a scope inside of the `axis` environment. For `matlab2tikz` users that may need such approach, here is the `matlab` code used to modify the `tex` file generated by `matlab2tikz`. It allows to batch process the files instead of modifiying them manually.

```
% Load tex file in workspace as cell
texfile = importdata(texfilepath);
% Find begin and end of axis content
beginaxisline = find(cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,']')==1,texfile));
endaxisline = find(cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,'\end{axis}')==1,texfile));

% Determine modifications to be added depending of figure contents
% Lines to be added after \begin{axis}[...] stored as the lines of a cell
beginaxismod = {...;...;...};
% Lines to be added before \end{axis} stored as the lines of a cell
endaxismod = {...;...;...};
% Assembly of the new tex file contents
texfilemod = [texfile(1:beginaxisline,1) ; ...
              beginaxismod; ...
              texfile((beginaxisline+1):(endaxisline-1),1);...
              endaxismod; ...
              texfile(endaxisline:end,1)...
             ];

% Overwrite modified .tex file
fid = fopen(texfilepath,'rt+');
fprintf(fid,'%s\n', texfilemod{:});
fclose(fid);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\begin{axis}[/tikz/every node/.append style={inner sep=0pt}]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a axis, you are in the `pgfplots` directory, so you'd need to switch to `tikz`. If you don't want to mess up the axis labels, use a scope.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Now working solution 1 : nothing seems to happen
\begin{axis}[/tikz/every node/.append style={inner sep=0pt}]
\addplot[domain=0:10] {x};
\node[fill=orange,draw=black] at (axis cs: (5,5) {Hello World};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Now working solution 2 : nothing seems to happen
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:10] {x};
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={inner sep=0pt}]
\node[fill=orange,draw=black] at (axis cs: (5,5) {Hello World};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was afraid, there was no other option than to modify the content of the `axis` manually, that is why I did not consider a scope at first. All this is due to way `matlab2tikz` works. You can pass options to the `axis` within `matlab`, but AFAIK there is no direct way to provide a a wrapper inside the `axis`. Do you think something like `execute at begin axis` could allow to do this ?

Comment: @BambOo I am not sure if an `execute at begin axis` alone will help, but maybe if you set these things with `execute at end plot={\tikzset{...}}` and unset them with `execute at end axis={\tikzset{....}}`, it could work. I did not try these things out. (But I guess that the axis labels are drawn at a very late stage, when pgfplots knows how large the plots are, yet I do not know for sure, so one has to try out.

Comment: @BambOo I tried several combinations, none of them had the desired effect... :-(

Comment: I finally chose the `scope` approach. As I said before, there is no direct way to add such wrapper in `matlab2tikz` options, so I wrote a small piece of `matlab` code that patches the original `tex` file. I updated my question to share this