# How to control font size with a standalone pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, fontsize, standalone, matlab2tikz

I want to control the font size of an embedded, standalone pgfplot. I realized it by defining a `\newcommand` (see the MWE).

My question is, is there a better solution?

Maybe I should mention that the plot `tikzpic.tex` is generated with `matlab2tikz`.

MWE.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\newlength{\figHeight}%
\newlength{\figWidth}%
\setlength{\figHeight}{3.5cm}%
\setlength{\figWidth}{7.5cm}%
\newcommand{\myFontSize}{\normalsize}%
\includestandalone{./tikzpic}
\caption{Caption}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

tikzpic.tex:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
%\newlength{\figHeight}%
%\newlength{\figWidth}%
%\setlength{\figHeight}{5.5cm}%
%\setlength{\figWidth}{14cm}%
%\newcommand{\myFontSize}{\footnotesize}%
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font={\myFontSize}] 

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.951\figWidth,
height=\figHeight,
at={(0\figWidth,0\figHeight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=-110.00,
xmax=110.00,
xlabel={ x-Label },
ymin=-0.10,
ymax=3.10,
ylabel={ y-Label },
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={at={(0.5,0.03)}, anchor=south},
xtick align=outside,
xtick pos=bottom,
xticklabel style={align=center, text width=1em, /pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision=0, /pgf/number format/use comma, /pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,}, scaled x ticks = false},
xlabel style={ font={\myFontSize\color{black}} },
ytick distance=0.5,
ytick align=outside,
ytick pos=left,
yticklabel style={align=center, text width=1em, /pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision=1, /pgf/number format/use comma, /pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,} scaled y ticks = false},
ylabel style={ font={\myFontSize\color{black}} },
legend style={ font={\myFontSize\color{black}} },
]
\addplot [color=black, line width=1.5pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
-100.00 1.\\
100.00  2.\\
};
\addlegendentry{LegendEntry}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, macro definitions inside an environment (figure) are local to the environment, so \def will do.  Not sure about \newlength.

Comment: \newlength is global, so don't use it too much.  (It calls \newskip which calls \alloc which globally increments count register 12.)

Comment: BTW, I also run into the problem that the `pgfplotsset` settings are not accepted in the standalone plot. [The problem arises due to a bug in matlab2tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329315/pgfplotsset-append-style-is-not-appended-to-tikzpicture-axis-environment)

Comment: @John Kormylo: Are there better solutions with which the size of the plot and the font size can be adjusted individually for each image of a document? With the condition that all images can also be generated standalone?

Comment: I don't (can't) use shell escapes, and have no idea how information is transmitted between the programs.  You could write the \pgfplotset command to a file and \input it in the standalone.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to use `\pgfplotsset`. In this settings, different control ways are possible. A minor changes were made in your `tikzpic.tex` file.

Main File:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{standalone}
\newlength{\figHeight}%
\newlength{\figWidth}%
\setlength{\figHeight}{3.5cm}%
\setlength{\figWidth}{7.5cm}%
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

%\newcommand{\myFontSize}{\Large}%
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
  y label style={font=\Huge},
  x label style={font=\Huge},
  tick label style={font=\Huge},
  legend style={nodes={scale=1, transform shape}}, 
  legend style={at={(0.5,0.03)}, anchor=south},
  every tick label/.append style={font=\fontsize{13}{20}\selectfont}  
                    }}
\includestandalone{./tikzpic}
\caption{Caption}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
  y label style={font=\large},
  x label style={font=\Huge},
  tick label style={font=\Huge},
  legend style={nodes={scale=1.5, transform shape}}, 
  legend style={at={(0.5,0.03)}, anchor=south},
  every tick label/.append style={font=\fontsize{13}{20}\selectfont}  
                    }}
\includestandalone{./tikzpic}
\caption{Caption}
\label{figure2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

tikzpic.tex:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
%\newlength{\figHeight}%
%\newlength{\figWidth}%
%\setlength{\figHeight}{5.5cm}%
%\setlength{\figWidth}{14cm}%
%\newcommand{\myFontSize}{\footnotesize}%
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[font={\myFontSize}] 

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.951\figWidth,
height=\figHeight,
at={(0\figWidth,0\figHeight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=-110.00,
xmax=110.00,
xlabel={ x-Label },
ymin=-0.10,
ymax=3.10,
ylabel={ y-Label },
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
%legend style={at={(0.5,0.03)}, anchor=south},
xtick align=outside,
xtick pos=bottom,
xticklabel style={align=center, text width=1em, /pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision=0, /pgf/number format/use comma, /pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,}, scaled x ticks = false},
%xlabel style={ font={\color{black}} },
ytick distance=0.5,
ytick align=outside,
ytick pos=left,
yticklabel style={align=center, text width=1em, /pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision=1, /pgf/number format/use comma, /pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,} scaled y ticks = false},
%ylabel style={ font={\color{black}} },
legend style={ font={\color{black}} },
]
\addplot [color=black, line width=1.5pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
-100.00 1.\\
100.00  2.\\
};
\addlegendentry{LegendEntry}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Output with my settings:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Does the `\pgfplotsset`-settings only affect the next image or does it affect all TiKz images in the document? What has to be done that the settings affect only the following image?

Comment: Only affect the following image. I have edit my my answer according to this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution :-)

Comment: @TomTom, You welcome.